# Unable to cast object of type 'Npgsql.PoolingDataSource' to type 'Npgsql.MultiplexingDataSource' - InvalidCastException during call to Postgres

Tags: c#, .net, postgresql

I faced very weird issue during some development against Postgres.

Here is the code:

```
using Npgsql;
///class, constructor, all the definitions here
NpgsqlConnection _connection = new NpgsqlConnection("ConnectionString");

_connection.Open();

string command = "my command with param @param";

using var npgsqlCommand = new NpgsqlCommand(command, _connection);
npgsqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@param", myparam);

using NpgsqlDataReader reader = npgsqlCommand.ExecuteReader();
    
while (reader.Read())
{
    //do some staff 
}
```

The exception was thrown only once, the rest of the time everything works without problems, thousand call per day

Do you have any ideas what was the problem?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how related, but I saw the same error, using dapper to make calls with Npgsql as the `IDbConnection` provider.  Tracked it down to not awaiting an async call prior to the offending method call.

Interestingly, I ran the same code using `Microsoft.Data.Sqlite` as the `IDbConnection` provider — again with Dapper — but didn't catch the error.